# Are there ever any Superuser or SE site "meetups"?

Tags: discussion, community

Are there ever any events where Super User, Stack Overflow and/or other SE site members meet up and exchange hello's, discuss stuck keys, errors messages and the like, or generally engage one another as nerds might do?

Answer (score 1):

About two years ago there was a [Stack Overflow meet up.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/stack-overflow-meetups-april-6/) We also [had on in 2012](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/stack-overflow-meetup-everywhere-april-28-2012/). There has not really been much since, as far as I know. However, we used a site called MeetUp, which is still active and shows users that were signed up in the area. I'm sure if enough people showed some interest in doing another day like this, it could get more official support from [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

I think it would be cool anyway, it's not overly difficult to setup, besides trying to find a good location.

Comment: Melbourne would be a great location

Comment: @Paul Australia is a tad far for me ;)

Comment: I'm fairly close to Detroit. I hear there's a lot of space available there now. :)

Comment: There was also this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156776/come-to-our-berlin-launch-party-of-careers-2-0-in-german

Comment: Mumbai anyone? ;)

Comment: There is even the [Not a Robot](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot) badge (on SO) for "Met a Stack Overflow employee at an event where Stack Overflow was an organizer or participant with 50 or more attendees."